# two title pages in the book without restarting the pagenumbering

Tags: titles, page-numbering

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}
\input{Brillpreamble}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\include{titleBrill}
\include{abbrevBrill}
\include{prefaceandintroBrill}
\mainmatter
\input{./title1.tex}
\include{text1}
\input{./title2.tex}
\include{text2}
\backmatter
\printindex[nominum]
\printindex[rerum]
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\include{Biblio}
\end{document}
```

this is my preambleBrill code:

```
% XeLaTeX can use any Mac OS X font. See the setromanfont command below.
% Input to XeLaTeX is full Unicode, so Unicode characters can be typed directly into the source.

% The next lines tell TeXShop to typeset with xelatex, and to open and save the source with Unicode encoding.

%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ledmac}
\linenummargin{inner}
\sidenotemargin{outer}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{adforn}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\textheight = 180.5 mm
\textwidth = 108.5 mm
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{12pt}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \noindent\makebox[1em][r]{\@makefnmark}#1}
\makeatother
\usepackage{imakeidx} 
\makeindex[name=nominum, title=Index nominum, columns=2]
\makeindex[name=rerum, title=Index rerum, columns=2]
\pretolerance=100
\usepackage{microtype}
\makeatletter
% And in the paragraphed footnotes, I'd like no colon too:
\def\parafootfmt#1#2#3{%
  \normal@pars
  \parindent=0pt \parfillskip=0pt plus 1fil
  {\bf\printlines#1|}%
  {\select@lemmafont#1|#2}~%
  #3\penalty-10 }
\makeatother
\let\Afootfmt\parafootfmt

%\newcommand{\rhet}[2]{\edtext{#1}{\Afootnote{#2}}}
\newcommand{\rhet}[2]{\edtext{ #1}{\Afootnote{] #2}}}
\newcommand{\oed}[2]{\edtext{ #1}{\Bfootnote{] #2}}}
\footparagraph{A}
\footparagraph{B}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\raggedbottom


\newcommand*{\LeftWidth}{3.0cm}%
\newcommand*{\RightWidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\LeftWidth-2em\relax}%
\newcommand{\AlignedBrace}[2]{%
    \medskip\par\noindent%
    \parbox{\LeftWidth}{\raggedleft\textbf{#1}\strut~}%
    $\left\{~\parbox{\RightWidth}{\strut\textit{#2}\strut}\right.$%
}%


%\usepackage{geometry}                % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
%\geometry{a4paper}                   % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
%\geometry{landscape}                % Activate for for rotated page geometry
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}    % Activate to begin paragraphs with an empty line rather than an indent
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amssymb}
%\renewcommand %These two commands are for double-spacing
%\baselinestretch{2}

% Will Robertson's fontspec.sty can be used to simplify font choices.
% To experiment, open /Applications/Font Book to examine the fonts provided on Mac OS X,
% and change "Hoefler Text" to any of these choices.

\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Brill}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text]{Gill Sans}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Andale Mono}
\frenchspacing

\newfontfamily{\H}[Scale=0.9]{Lucida Grande}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{aboveskip=5pt}

\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist
```

Comment: And what's behind `titleBrill`? And in `abbrevBrill`? What are you doing there? How should we guess what we could do? I suppose some `\maketitle` in there, but ... it's a guess

Comment: The `titlepage` environment isn't doing a lot. Checks for one/twocolumn, sets the pagestyle to empty *and* sets the pagenumber. Just don't use it and you will be fine (keep `\thispagestyle{empty}` though). On the other hand, KOMA-classes have that thing which is a leftover of an almost 30 years old bug.

Comment: @Johannes_B: On the other hand, no one is forced to use `\maketitle` or the `titlepage` environment ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The whole point of my comment. Looking at it again, it misses a *don't* which makes it sound like KOMA has the compat-*feature*. I am very in favour of *not* using `\maketitle`. It is probably one of the most missleading commands a starter can encounter.

Comment: @Johannes_B: I understood it basically that way, however, my language was wrong. I wanted to emphasize your statement, but reading it again, it's sound like `objection` ;-)

Comment: so what do you suggest I do? I'd like to keep the same pagination in the mainmatter.

Comment: @GuillaumeCoatalen: We can't suggest anything as long we do not know what you have written actually. Code in `\include{...}` is invisible to us

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I've added the preamble, but the rest is awfully long, this is a 300 page long book.

Comment: this is my "titleBrill" file: \title{Two treatises}
\author{Guillaume Coatalen}
\date{}
\maketitle

Comment: Read [How to customize my titlepage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/209993) and create them on your own. Don't use `titlepage` though, as this will lead to the described behaviour.

Comment: thanks, but what about the pagination? Could I keep the same one in the mainmatter?

Comment: Yes. Just don't change it. You don't have to use `\frontmatter` or `\mainmatter` at all. This is off-topic but your preamble is a mess. Why are you loading `lmodern`? Or `fancyhdr`? It is better not to use single character names for custom commands. It would also be better to use `geometry` to specify the page layout dimensions rather than doing it manually.

Comment: I thought I needed fancyhdr for headers notably in the indexes.

Comment: and \frontmatter for Latin numerals.

Comment: @cfr, better use whatever mechanism your format uses to select a standard page layout. The layouts in use are the result of centuries of experience, you shouldn't go against handed down wisdom without solid reasons.

Comment: @vonbrand I was talking about the best way to change them given that they are being changed. Whether they should be changed and, if so, what they should be changed to is surely a different question. But, actually, I doubt very much that the formats in use by LaTeX for standard paper sizes are the result of 'centuries of experience'. Were they really using A4 or US letter paper in the 1500s? I might be mistaken, but it seems rather unlikely. In fact, the standard classes do *not* layout pages according to such conventions - see the manuals for KOMA and `memoir` for complaints about this!

Comment: In the meantime, this same question was introduced in http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=26520&p=90831#p90831

Comment: for which I still haven't got an answer.

Comment: You've still not provided a Minimum Working Example (MWE) either.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with `\maketitle` is, that it is a command that disables itself after being called by using `\global\let\maketitle\relax` (the same is true for `\title`, `\author` etc.

This can be disabled either be redefining `\maketitle` or using `\xpatch` and removing the relevant code.

This will prevent the restart of the pagenumbering anyway.

The next culprit is that `book` uses `titlepage` implicitly. If this option is used, the maketitle uses `\begin{titlepage}...\end{titlepage}` which will automatically reset the page number.

I provide the `notitlepage` version here for the moment and try to get the `titlepage` beast later on.

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{book}



\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcounter{titlescntr}

\makeatletter

\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{\par
}{%
  \par%
  \stepcounter{titlescntr}
  \ifnum\value{titlescntr} > 0 
  \cleardoublepage
  \fi
}{}{}

\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{%
  \global\let\thanks\relax
  \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@thanks\@empty
  \global\let\@author\@empty
  \global\let\@date\@empty
  \global\let\@title\@empty
  \global\let\title\relax
  \global\let\author\relax
  \global\let\date\relax
  \global\let\and\relax
}{%
  \clearpage
}{\typeout{Patched!}}{\typeout{Patching failed!}}

\makeatother

\title{Two treatises} 
\author{Guillaume Coatalen} 
\date{} 

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\maketitle 

\title{Theory of Brontosaurs}
\author{Ann Elk}
\maketitle

\blindtext


\end{document}
```

**Updated: Removing the resetting of the page number if `titlepage` is used**

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{book}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\newcounter{titlescntr}

\makeatletter

\if@titlepage
\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{%
  \global\let\thanks\relax
  \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@thanks\@empty
  \global\let\@author\@empty
  \global\let\@date\@empty
  \global\let\@title\@empty
  \global\let\title\relax
  \global\let\author\relax
  \global\let\date\relax
  \global\let\and\relax
}{%
}{\typeout{patched maketitle for titlepage}}{}

\xpatchcmd{\titlepage}{%
  \setcounter{page}\@ne
}{%
}{\typeout{patched titlepage}}{}

\xpatchcmd{\endtitlepage}{%
  \setcounter{page}\@ne
}{%
}{\typeout{patched endtitlepage}}{}

\else

\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{\par
}{%
  \par% 
  \stepcounter{titlescntr}
  \ifnum\value{titlescntr} > 0 % Make a new page for the next title
  \cleardoublepage
  \fi
}{}{}

\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{%
  \global\let\thanks\relax
  \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@thanks\@empty
  \global\let\@author\@empty
  \global\let\@date\@empty
  \global\let\@title\@empty
  \global\let\title\relax
  \global\let\author\relax
  \global\let\date\relax
  \global\let\and\relax
}{%
  \clearpage
}{\typeout{Patched!}}{\typeout{Patching failed!}}
\fi

\makeatother

\title{Two treatises} 
\author{Guillaume Coatalen} 
\date{} 

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\maketitle 

\title{Theory of Brontosaurs}
\author{Ann Elk}
\maketitle

\blindtext


\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) But much too much work!

Answer (score 5):

I'm lazy. If somebody else has already done the work and I can use theirs, I figure there's no need for me to spend time poring over different designs for the newfangled invention they call a 'wheel'.

---

I would use **etoolbox** to patch the `titlepage` environment which `book` uses for titles by default, and let **titling** do the rest.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox,titling}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\titlepage}{\setcounter{page}\@ne}{}{\message {Successfully patched titlepage.}}{\message {Failed to patch titlepage.}}
\makeatother
```

The patch simply stops the use of `titlepage` by `\maketitle` from restarting the numbering scheme. However, we'll still get numbering from 1 when we first switch to Arabic numerals in the main matter because `\mainmatter` takes care of that automatically.

Loading **titling** allows us to use the regular `\title`, `\author`, `\date`, `\maketitle` commands as many times as we like in the document.

```
\title{Title 1}
\author{Author 1}
\date{Date 1}
\maketitle

\title{Title 2}
\author{Author 2}
\date{Date 2}
\maketitle
```

[I'm not against the use of `\maketitle` although it can, obviously, have unwanted effects when misunderstood and is, perhaps, unfortunately named. In any case, since it is easy to use and keeps my code here simple, I would see no reason to look a gift horse in the mouth, even if I had general doubts about the horse's value in other contexts.]

Because you are already using `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`, there's no need to worry about setting the kind of page numbering as the `book` class uses lower-case Roman numerals for the front matter and Arabic numerals for the main matter by default.

```
\frontmatter
```

switches to lower-case Roman numerals, starting from 1.

```
\mainmatter
```

then switches to Arabic numerals, restarting the count from 1.

[image: two title pages, lower-case Roman and continuous Arabic numbering]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox,titling}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\titlepage}{\setcounter{page}\@ne}{}{\message {Successfully patched titlepage.}}{\message {Failed to patch titlepage.}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\kant[1-5]
\mainmatter
\title{Title 1}
\author{Author 1}
\date{Date 1}
\maketitle
\kant[6-10]
\title{Title 2}
\author{Author 2}
\date{Date 2}
\maketitle
\kant[11-15]
\backmatter
\kant[16-20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Much too easy, using other packages :-P